# Reboot_AC overriding sleep timer even though it's disabled, computer won't sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Trying to figure out why my wife's computer won't go to sleep from the sleep timer.  The screens turn off, but the computer is still awake and the fans rev every now and again giving the impression it's working on something.

Running lastwake returns this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Wake Timer
    Owner: [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker)
    Owner Supplied Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot_AC' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.
```

So I went into the task scheduler to find the task already disabled.  The weird part is it is listed as disabled today 2/10/21 even though this is the first time I've checked on it.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator`
2. Rename the `Reboot_AC` file to `Reboot_AC.bak`
3. Create a new folder named `Reboot_AC`

This will completely cripple that task, and also prevent Windows Update from repairing it, since a folder with that filename already exists.